# Form fails to create new child object with mongoid 1-n reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, forms, mongoid

So, I have two forms to create objects. I can create and `Owner` with just a `name`. Now, I want to create a `Listing` with a `name` and assign it to an `Owner`. I can create a new `Listing` when I don't have the 1-n relations set up, but when I have `Listing` `belongs_to :owner` the form no longer works.

Models:

```
class Owner
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :listings

  field :name, type: String

end


class Listing
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :owner

  field :name, type: String

end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for @listing do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name, "Listing Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :listing, "Owner" %>
    <%= f.collection_select :owner_id, Owner.all, :id, :name, prompt: true %>
  </div>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>    
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def new
    @listing = Listing.new
end

def create
    @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)

    if @listing.save
        redirect_to @listing, notice: "Listing Creation >> SUCCESS" and return
    end
    render :new
end



private

    def listing_params
      params.require(:listing).permit(:name, owner_attributes: [:name])
    end
```

My form generates properly in the sense that I get the field to enter a name and a dropdown list with each `Owner`, but the form doesn't create the new `Listing`. I don't understand because when I remove the `has_many` and `belongs_to` relations the forms and object creation work okay.

Please keep in mind that I'm very very new to this :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few changes needed here:

Form:

```
<%= form_for @listing do |f| %>
  ...
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :owner, "Owner" %>     # :owner instead of :listing
    <%= f.collection_select :owner_id, Owner.all, :id, :name, prompt: true %>
  </div>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def create
  @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)

  if @listing.save
    redirect_to @listing, notice: "Listing Creation >> SUCCESS" and return
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private

def listing_params
  params.require(:listing).permit(:name, :owner_id)
end
```

Please revert and add the rails log for the `create` request if it doesn't work.

Comment: Wow... thank you so much for taking the time to help me!! This fixed it! I am still super new to this and I keep finding myself putting the cart before the horse... I'm glad to find out that I was able to communicate the issue clear enough for you to solve for me. Thanks again :D